# Please add a Viewer option to disable AggregatedView.updateHomeCamera

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

It took a lot of work to setup my viewer camera perfectly before/while models are loading.

Unfortunately `AggregatedView.updateHomeCamera` resets the view cube and causes a lot of unnecessary work by calling `autocam.sync` and `autocam.setHomeViewFrom`. Since `updateHomeCamera` is a free-standing function I can't patch it out directly.

Please add a option to disable `updateHomeCamera` or at least make it a member function so we can patch it.

My current workaround is patching `autocam.sync` and `autocam.setHomeViewFrom`

```js
  const nativeSync = viewer.autocam.sync.bind(viewer.autocam)

  const sync = (camera) => {
    if (camera.position instanceof Autodesk.Viewing.Private.LmvVector3) return
    nativeSync(camera)
  }

  viewer.autocam.sync = sync
```

This is very bad, but at least my camera and viewcube is working.

Comment: I'm checking this with our engineering team. Our apologies for the inconvenience.

Comment: Hi Eason. Thanks a lot for checking back with the devs. It's very much possible that I'm doing it wrong. What I'm trying to achieve is a) setting a custom home camera depending on which model is loaded (eg. switching projects with persistent aggregated view) and b) initialize with a custom camera position/rotation based on url parameters.

Comment: My setup already works surprisingly well. I probably need to write a blog post on how to store the camera efficiently in the url (I'm down to 2x vec3 + a quaternion). My problem is the view cube starts to render in the correct orientation but then snaps back to default when I don't patch the above mentioned functions.